# Testing post method Spring

Tags: spring, mocking, spring-3, spring-test

I would like to test the controller method below. Is there any way to add a Profile object the
mock request?

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
//request.add(myProfile);

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View postUser(ModelMap data, @Valid Profile profile) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your profile object should be bound based on what is submitted as request parameters, so just set the relevant request parameters, say for eg, if you have a field in Profile as name, set that request. `request.addParameter("name", "val")`

A very good way of testing the Spring MVC stack is using [Spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc)

Comment: As you can se i need a complete Profile oject. My profile cant be a String?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is your profile will be created by Spring MVC stack based on what you pass in as request parameters. Say for eg, if your Profile class had fields for id, name etc, you are expected to pass in id, name etc and Spring MVC stack will bind those request parameters into Profile object(it will create a Profile object, map the id, name fields to the fields in the Profile object).

Comment: What do I put in the Profile when calling the method?